# How to make the entire asp.net solution as a user control

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, wcf

How to make the entire asp.net solution as a user control so that it could be used with other application.i have a asp.net solution including the wcf services in it. I want to make it a user control so that it could be used as if like a user control with other application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is a `iframe` like this:

```
<iframe src="http://www.YourSite.com/page.aspx" width="400px" height="300px" />
```